# How do you modify the body content of the response associated with an upload request in fineuploader?

Tags: javascript, json, fine-uploader

I am currently using [FineUploader](http://fineuploader.com/demos.html) to upload a file using the `uploader.uploadStoredFiles()` method.  Using a network packet analyzer, I observe once the upload request has been sent, a JSON response is returned containing `success=true` or `success=false` property among many other properties.

Under normal conditions, this JSON response is parsed in Javascript and dealt with appropriately. However, I wish to add a custom attribute (something like "mycusattr", "my custom value") to the JSON structure, so that I can parse it with all the attributes in Javascript like I normally do.

Does anyone know where the JSON structure in an upload response is defined, and if so, can I add one more custom attribute to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may return whatever properties you'd like from your server in your JSON response, and they will be made available to you in your [`onComplete` callback handler](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#complete). For example, suppose your response, in addition to `"success": true`, contains a "foo" property with a value of "bar". You can access this property as follows:

```
var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
   /* ... other init options ... */

   callbacks: {
      onComplete: function(id, name, response) {
         console.log(response.foo) // prints "bar"
      }
   }
})
```

Comment: Would it be possible to access a response header as well inside the onComplete? I added a header to the response within the server-side code (something like response.addHeader("foo","bar")), and I tried to see if I could access it in the callback by doing console.log(response.foo), but there was nothing returned.  The strangest part about all this is I can see the header is correctly added in the Network Packet analyzer I'm using! So how come my browser sees the header but Javascript / Fineuploader does not?

Comment: It's very odd that you are using a "network packet analyzer" to look at an http request - using browser dev tools is much more appropriate. Anyway there isn't any issue with "seeing" these headers. Take a look at the fourth parameter passed to onComplete in the doc page I linked to. The entire xhr object is avaiable, and you can access response headers from that object.